# Django static file href incorrectly formatted

Tags: python, html, css, django

So I have the following static loading in Django with `DEBUG=True`:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
```

Now in my `settings.py` I have the following:

```py
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

When I run the server `python manage.py runserver` and inspect my webpage in the console, the sources appear correctly, but the `href` attribute points to `/static/css/styles.css`, rather than `static/css/styles.css` (notice the omission of the leading `/`). Notice that the `href` on line `18` points to the wrong folder, but `static/css` appears correctly in the sources.

[image: points to wrong folder]

So, clearly django, behind the scenes, just replaces `{% static 'css/styles.css' %}` with `STATIC_URL + 'css/styles.css'`. If I now change `STATIC_URL` to

```py
STATIC_URL = "static/"
```

The `href` is correct (points to the right file) but the files themselves are not present!!

[image]

So in order for the css file to appear, `STATIC_URL` needs to be `/static/`, but the `href` references a non-existent directory. If I change `STATIC_URL` to `static/` the `href` is correct, but the files don't appear! Does anyone know how to fix this? I feel like it's such a basic problem, but it's doing my head in...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Restart server and then clear cache before load